# run RequestRestartAsync to launch app normally

Tags: uwp

is there any way to run RestartRequestAsync without any specific arguments so the app just restarts normally? I am trying to have my app automatically restart whenever the user closes it manually. This is what I have so far:

```
private async void OnMainPageCloseRequest(object sender, SystemNavigationCloseRequestedPreviewEventArgs e)
{
 
       await CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync("");

}
```

when I run this code, nothing happens when I close the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent your users from terminating your app, you should explicitly declare the `confirmAppClose` restricted capability in your app manifest and handle the `CloseRequested` as suggested [here](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2018/09/app-close-confirmation-in-uwp/).

You cannot prevent the app from terminating by simply calling `RequestRestartAsync`. And the argument that you pass to the `RequestRestartAsync` API is just any `string`. Whether it restarts "normally" depends on what you do with this value when your app gets activated.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to prevent users from terminating an external app you launch through the program instead of the main page?